# Oracle stored function with temp table

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, temporary

I created a temporary table and a stored function to read it. when i call it following message appears:

```
RA-22905: Zugriff auf Zeilen eines Objekts, das keine Nested Table ist, nicht möglich
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
*Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
           parse time or that is not of a nested table type
*Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type
Fehler in Zeile: 3 Spalte: 15
```

So, how can I do that CAST thing?

My beloved function:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY testlho2 IS 
  FUNCTION getBasicDate (app_in IN varchar2, termc_in IN varchar2) 
    return sys_refcursor is 
    l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR; 
  BEGIN 
    -- Populate temporary table 
    INSERT INTO temp_tab_test_lho2 (app, sla, tsl) 
      SELECT app, sla, tslstat 
      FROM pmon_orig_file 
      WHERE app = app_in and termcause = termc_in; 
    -- Open REF CURSOR for Output 
    open l_rc for 
      select app, sla, tsl 
      from temp_tab_test_lho2; 
    return l_rc; 
  END; 
END testlho2 ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-22905 - when quering a table type with a select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208264/ora-22905-when-quering-a-table-type-with-a-select-statement)

Comment: Sorry, my crystall ball is out of order. If you publish your function, maybe somebody will can say how to repair it.

Comment: create or replace PACKAGE BODY testlho2 IS FUNCTION getBasicDate  (app_in IN  varchar2, termc_in IN  varchar2) return sys_refcursor is l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR; BEGIN
  (-- Populate temporary table)
  INSERT INTO temp_tab_test_lho2
    (app, sla, tsl)
  SELECT app, sla, tslstat
  FROM   pmon_orig_file
  WHERE  app = app_in
 and termcause = termc_in;

   (-- Open REF CURSOR for Output)
  open l_rc
   for select app, sla, tsl
         from temp_tab_test_lho2;         
  return l_rc; 
END;
END testlho2 ;

Comment: this is my beloved function

Comment: At first look I didn't see any cause for ORA-22905. Are table fields all ordinally typed? BTW, do you really need of temp table? Why you don't just return select from pmon_orig_file?

Comment: my table: CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "PMON"."TEMP_TAB_TEST_LHO2" 
   ( "APP" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
 "SLA" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
 "TSL" TIMESTAMP (6)
   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;

Comment: wha temp table? i try to create some kind of a View. We use jasperreports and if you have lots of subreports, these is a huge advantage.

Comment: ... or just run the select straight from pmon_orig_file -- not sure what a temporary table adds to this.

Answer (score 0):

Temp table:

```
create global temporary table tbl(name_ varchar2(50))
/
```

Function:

```
create or replace function foo(app_in IN varchar2)
return sys_refcursor is 
l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR; 
begin
  insert into tbl select app_in from dual;
  open l_rc for select name_ from tbl;
  return l_rc;
end;
/
```

selecting the data from the function:

```
select * from table(foo('hiiii'));
```

Error:

```
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
```

If one want to use the function as above it must return a `type`.
see the below question:

[Function return sys_refcursor call from sql with specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690110/function-return-sys-refcursor-call-from-sql-with-specific-columns)

If you use the function in an anonymous block then it will work:

```
declare
l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR; 
begin
l_rc := foo('hiii');
end;
/

anonymous block completed
```

Even if you solve the return type issue with `type`, if you use the function in a `select` statement then it will error out saying:

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
14551. 00000 -  "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query "
```

Here it says how one can solve the above problem

[Solution to "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729236/solution-to-cannot-perform-a-dml-operation-inside-a-query)