# ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query error while using Execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XXCHR_UPDATE      (
                                                                P_SALESREP_ID          IN   NUMBER,
                                                                p_COLUMN_NAME           IN     VARCHAR2,
                                                                P_COLUMN_VALUE            IN   varchar2
                                                           )
   RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

   lv_dyn_sql                        VARCHAR2(2000):= NULL;

BEGIN


        lv_dyn_sql := 'UPDATE thirty_days
                SET attribute86 ='||p_COLUMN_NAME||',attribute87 ='||P_COLUMN_VALUE
                || 'WHERE SALESREP_ID = :1';     

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_dyn_sql using P_SALESREP_ID;

    return(1);



EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);
         --lv_return_val:= 0;
     RETURN SQLERRM;

END XXCHR_UPDATE;
```

When I execute this function its returning error

> ORA-14551

please suggest here

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you do with this function. `select XXCHR_UPDATE (a,b,c) from dual;` ?

Comment: maybe you need add quotes in your dyn sql ? because when you output sql string, you can see what attribute87 = attr, but need attribute87 = 'attr'

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729236/solution-to-cannot-perform-a-dml-operation-inside-a-query btw you seem to be missing a space between `p_column_value` and your `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to modify your statement:

```
lv_dyn_sql := 'UPDATE thirty_days
                SET attribute86 ='||p_COLUMN_NAME||',attribute87 ='||P_COLUMN_VALUE
                || 'WHERE SALESREP_ID = :1';
```

to

```
lv_dyn_sql := 'UPDATE thirty_days
                SET attribute86 ='||p_COLUMN_NAME||',attribute87 ='||P_COLUMN_VALUE
                || 'WHERE SALESREP_ID ='||P_SALESREP_ID;
```

and of course:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_dyn_sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't all three parameters? Get rid of the string joins:

```
lv_dyn_sql := q'[UPDATE thirty_days
                    SET attribute86 = :arg1
                      , attribute87 = :arg2
                  WHERE SALESREP_ID = :arg3]';

execute immediate lv_dy_sql using p_column_name, p_column_value, p_salesrepid;
```