# Oracle / update query inside pipelined table function

Tags: oracle

I have a pipelined table function that work fine.

what I need now is to perform an update query inside this function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION test(A varchar2 )
 RETURN type_As PIPELINED  as row_type type_A;
Begin
....
update X set A=0 where B=1;
select type_A(...) 
  into   row_type 
  from   dual;
PIPE ROW(row_type);
  return ;
end;
```

When I run this query :

> SELECT * from
>   TABLE(test('123'))

I get this error:

> ORA-14551:cannot perform a DML operation inside a query

So it's clear that a cannot add the update query here , so how to perform the update instead ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution to "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729236/solution-to-cannot-perform-a-dml-operation-inside-a-query)

Comment: @KaushikNayak No, this is not PIPELINED function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add

```
pragma autonomous_transaction;
```

to your function and use dynamic SQL for your update.

Comment: Using AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION means instant commit, and outer transactions that are rolled back will not roll back this "local" commit. So, it can have unpredicted consequenses in bigger scenarios.